# Visual Studio - Program displays differently than preview

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, windows-10, exe

My program as it exists in design view is not visually the same as the program that is executed. The bottom part of the UI seems to be cut off no matter how large I make the form. There is a status strip component docked at the bottom, but even removing this component doesn't fix the issue. I have provided a screenshot below. Does anyone know how or why this might be the case?

[image: running my application]

Along with online research, I've also tried adjusting my screen resolution to no avail. Below is my form load code:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TitlesTableAdapter.Fill(Me._booksDataSet.Titles)
    Me.PublishersTableAdapter.Fill(Me._booksDataSet.Publishers)
End Sub
```

I have double and triple checked that no part of my code changes or alters the display of the form in any way.

Comment: The two forms in your screenshot are different indeed. You mention there is a status strip component docked at the bottom, is it in both of those forms? Which ***form*** is causing you issues, your information details are lacking to help you further... Can you show the designer and the designer code of "BookData" form or whatever that is called...

Comment: I should have clarified: there is only one form in my project: `frmMain.vb`. The form you see running and the form in the designer view are the same form.

Comment: There could be a `frmMain.Height = 600` in `frmMain_Load` for all we know. You need to provide some code.

Comment: @djv added my form load code

Comment: My point is that the size could be changed by anything - a Timer, Resize event handler, your `updatePosition()` method for example. So it's hard to say exactly what the problem is. You can't post all your code, so it seems like the problem is too broad. If you could narrow it down to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it can help us to help you.

Comment: My guess is that your monitor is set to something other than the standard DPI.